# Windows Server 2003 stops sharing a folder when the server reboots

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share

I have a file server that will stop sharing a particular folder once the server is rebooted. This problem happened after the server went through a p2v migration. There are no events that seem to correlate to this issue.

I was reading http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/870964 but I don't think this applies and there are other shares on the same drive that are still there after a reboot.

To be clear about the issue;

When the server reboots share x is no longer shared any more but share y and z are still there.

This has nothing to do with users not being able to see the share. On the server its self the folder that was shared is no longer shared. I wish I had more information to post but after hours on this issue I can't find a way to move forward.

Comment: Needs much, much more information to be answerable.  Until then, I suggest "harsh" interrogations of the users.  My users are always stealing IP addresses, so I can see one of them stealing a shared folder while the server's defenseless during a reboot.

Comment: Are all the filesystems local, as in within the VM, or are you using iSCSI, or some other SAN?  Shares not returning are usually related to the storage not being available when the server service starts.  What happens if you restart the **Server** service?  Do your shares re-appear?

Comment: @HopelessN00b why would I interrogate the users? The share stops "sharing" on the server.

Comment: @Zoredache The link that I posted describes what you are talking about.

Comment: Are share Y and Z on the same logical disk?

Comment: Did you check if the registry values defining the share (SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares) are truly gone after a restart? Do you see the same behavior when restarting the "server" service?

Comment: Please do not simply repost (substantially) identical questions -- Edit this one and we will re-open it when there's enough information for us to help you. While you're obviously making an effort to get us more information there's simply not enough here to help you yet: Servers do not simply "stop sharing folders" without being told to do so by someone/something - Either an admin is un-sharing the folder or some system process is doing so. Check your system logs for any "interesting" entries...

Comment: I've seen a very similar problem many many years ago on an old NT4 server, every time the server was rebooted, the shares would simply disappear. We never did find a solution, but we used a work around (run a batch file to re-create the shares after a reboot).

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff the other shares are on the same disk

Comment: @syneticon-dj That was going to be my next step. The server is a production server so it's hard to get downtime for it. The next time I can reboot it I'm going to see if the reg entry is actually being removed.

Comment: @voretaq7 I wouldn't have to repost if someone could explain to me how this is not a real question?! I have posted what I have tried so far and exactly what is going on. This is also posted in case someone else has run into this problem before but since this keeps getting closed no one will see it! Obviously "Servers do not simply "stop sharing folders"" but I have watched the server go down and come back up with the shares missin afterwards. The point of this question is to find out WHY or how to diag better. Also the logs were checked...like I said.

Comment: @Bryan I think that is what I might have to end up doing but I would also I like to find out why this happening as well.